# Autowire Enum in Spring Bean

Tags: spring-boot, enums

Iam trying to autowire an enum inside a spring Bean.I have not tried this before and not sure what is missing but when i do that i am getting parameter 0 of constructor in required a bean of type java.lang.string error.
Please find below the code i have created.

```
public interface TokenGenerator{
 String generateToken();
}

@Service
public enum  TokenGeneratorImpl implements TokenGenerator{

INSTANCE;

private string token;

public string  generateToken(){
    if(token == null){
      token="new token";
    }

    return token;
   }
}


@Service
public class ConnectionService {

 @Autowired
 private TokenGenerator generator

 public void getConnection(){
   for(int i =0; i< 1000; i++){
         Thread t = new Thread(() -> generator.generateToken());
          t.start();
      }
   }
 }
```

There are two issues:
1) Autowiring is not working  and I am getting

```
parameter 0 of constructor in required a bean of type java.lang.string error
```

2) If i call directly the Enum and generate the token then i found that this code is not thread safe and want to understand how I can make it thread safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By autowiring the TokenGeneratorImpl, you are trying to instantiate an ENUM which is not possible

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36710397/5001937

For 2nd Point
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/2531998/5001937

Comment: But this resolves the first part only.The scond part why Iam getting multiple threads initializing  token again and again if i directly make a call to 
    
    TokenGeneratorImpl.INSTANCE.generatetoken();

In my understanding enum instance is thread safe

Comment: For 2nd point https://stackoverflow.com/a/2531998/5001937

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do this is to create a separate bean responsible for registering the enum with the context. It would look something like this

```
@Component
public class EnumContextInject {

    public final GenericApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public EnumContextInject(GenericApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void inject() {
        applicationContext.registerBean(TokenGeneratorImpl.class, () -> TokenGeneratorImpl.INSTANCE);
    }
}
```

You would need to make sure anything requiring the instance is created after this is run maybe with `@DependsOn`